# How to print out exclusively even terms of a sequence?

Tags: difference-equations

I need to print out the first 20 even-numbered terms of the function $a_{n+1}=\frac{5}{a_n}$. I am capable of printing out each term with this code:

```
a[n_] := If[n == 1, 1, 12 + 5/a[n - 1]];
For[i = 1, i <= 20, i++, Print["a", i, "=", N[a[i], 6]]];
```

To filter out odds I tried this Python-y solution using If[] and Modular arithmetic.

```
a[n_] := If[n == 1, 1, 12 + 5/a[n - 1]];
For[i = 1, i <= 20, i++, 
 If[Mod[i, 2] == 2, Print["a", i, "=", N[a[i], 6], 0]]]
```

However, that code has been unsuccessful for me in solving this particular problem and I would like a code that can solve for every odd term or every third term. Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: In your first code snippet, change `i++`  to `i+=2`.  Does that produce the desired results?

Comment: Try `RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == 12 + 5/a[n], a[1] == 1}, a, {n, 2, 40, 2}]` and report back.

Comment: `Mod[i, 2]` will return `0` or `1` depending on the parity of `i`, but never `2`. (In general, the result will always be $0\leq n \mod m\leq m-1$). You need to use `Mod[i, 2] == 0` or simply `EvenQ[i]`

Comment: @LouisB Yes! That produces exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

You can obtain the closed-form expression with [`RSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html)

```
aa[n_] = a[n] /. RSolve[{a[n] == 12 + 5/a[n - 1], a[1] == 1}, a[n], n][[1]] //
   Simplify

(* -((5 ((1/5 (6 - Sqrt[41]))^
     n (5 + Sqrt[41]) + (-5 + Sqrt[41]) (1/5 (6 + Sqrt[41]))^n))/((1/
     5 (6 + Sqrt[41]))^n (-71 + 11 Sqrt[41]) + (1/5 (6 - Sqrt[41]))^
   n (71 + 11 Sqrt[41]))) *)
```

The sequence is then

```
aa /@ Range[2, 40, 2] // Simplify

(* {17, 2593/209, 398897/32161, 61365313/4947569, 9440285777/761121601, \
1452269876833/117089037329, 223413553887857/18012683708641, \
34369380551809153/2771026065197489, 5287299266131413137/426287696947697281, \
813384852470442394273/65579029678315444049, \
125129084798794843389617/10088513378036885951521, \
19249544437702644822144193/1551991584475722550433009, \
2961301616286237431525465297/238754491174810350617895361, \
455559210297137998334368050913/36729391851308900931395060369, \
70082085845352095807704543208177/5650357482822200484669391912801, \
10781252239926794304428140452786433/869236817558336152115801478062129, \
1658560792802592520486741016148906257/133721210966913212413716692823747841, \
255148830785601078297347412975611902753/\
20571335568465676307909475657905614289, \
39251455921162501244779333072840510367537/\
3164642647269541321107716333996870904481, \
6038345491089385164738583607893048299031873/\
486840684290297721542890578544070478932849} *)
```

In the limit the sequence goes to

```
Limit[aa[n], n -> Infinity]

(* 6 + Sqrt[41] *)
```

Alternatively,

```
Solve[{a == 12 + 5/a, a > 0}, a]

(* {{a -> 6 + Sqrt[41]}} *)
```